Does a Synagogue or Beit Midrash's Year-Round Illumination of an Electric Menorah Detract from פרסומי ניסא?
I have seen synagogues or batei midrashot that have an electric menorah on all year-round. Sometimes it is outside of the building and sometimes it's on the inside. All eight lamps are on. The menorah is not fashioned with seven lamps (in which case it would resemble the Menorah of the Mishkan, etc.), but with 8 a la Chanukah.
I realize that these institutions are not in any way trying to fulfill a Chanukah duty (nor am I suggesting that the use of electric bulbs fulfills such an obligation). Does this constant illumination detract from פרסומי ניסא? If a Chanukiah is illuminated perennially, doesn't this diminish the once-a-year lighting's ability to call attention to a specific historical miracle?
(There is precedent BTW for stopping an activity a day before in order to allow a Mitzva to stand out - not blowing the shofar on erev Rosh Hashanah and not eating Matza on erev Pesach. All the more reason to create some space in the case of  פרסומי ניסא.)

Never seen a 8 candle Menora for all year. Seen one that has 5 or 6.

Back in the old days before menorah for Chanukah, would you ask if lighting candles in shul year round detracts from lighting candles for Chanukah?

This sounds like an opinion question. In my opinion, any menorah used for Chanukah should be exclusive to Chanukah so that it is clear when used what the message is, and yes in my opinion any 8-branched menorah should not be lit year-round. I don't think that displaying it without lights would be a problem.
